# iOS download image from href a tag html

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, html, hybrid-mobile-app

I have something very simple.

I will put a simple bloburl to a href of an a tag.

```
<a id="downloadReady" class="btn btn-primary" download=""
   href="blob:https://pic2.conveyor.cloud/934d8e82-cfb2-43d4-b0f9-00822621f772">
   Download Ready!
</a>
```

Super simple.

On android, windows, blackberry etc it works.  On ios i get following message after 3 taps.

```
This website is repeatedly trying to open another application
```

Granted the image is large, not very but it was from iphone camera, on smaller images it works.

I cannot embed in jsbin because there is a bug currently. Maybe somebody can help me out?

Note: the code is used in a simple website, in the browser, not a native hybrid web app like ionic etc.

Comment: `Granted the image is large` - maybe wait for some time to see if its taking time to download

Comment: Its instant on android ,its ios anti popup system

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing exactly the same issue while downloading pdf on iOS using Chrome Browser.
I used fileReader approach to fix that. Also I added this under condition that this code should work only for Chrome on iOS.
Below is my code

```
 if (window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('crios') > -1) {
        const fileReader = new FileReader()
        const blobUrl = new Blob([serviceResponse.data], { type: 
        'application/pdf' })
          fileReader.onload = function (event) {
            window.location.href = reader.result
          }
          fileReader.readAsDataURL(blobUrl)
    }
```

Let me know in case you need further clarification.

Comment: The code above does not 'download the image', but mrely opens it in another tab.