# ReactJs - PDF download not working in iOS Chrome on iPad

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome

Problem stated as subject.

Looking at references [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49601384/ios-download-image-from-href-a-tag-html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39375076/how-to-display-pdf-blob-on-ios-sent-from-my-angularjs-app), I have following code, but it does not work.

My current code:

```
if (window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('crios') > -1) {
var byteCharacters = atob(this.state.base64EncodedPDF);
var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
    byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
}
var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
var blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: "application/octet-stream" });
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function () { reader.result; };
reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
return;
```

What is the problem here?

**EDIT**

If you wonder what was the error, there was no error. Nothing just happens when I clicked on the download link. Desktop browsers work fine (of course in other IF conditions).